# How to solve gcc or g++ errors related to clang?

Tags: android, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel

Made some changes in my android kernel and was trying to compile it but facing some error related to clang.

I've tried to manipulate clang and gcc flags but don't know which exactly should be add or remove.

```
extern "C"
{

int init_test()
{
    int n=5,i;
    TestClass **t;

    t = new TestClass* [n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
       t[i] = new TestClass(i);
       t[i]->print_version();
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        delete t[i];
    delete t;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  CC      kernel/test.o
real-aarch64-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-no-integrated-as'
real-aarch64-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-implicit-float'
real-aarch64-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-global-merge'
real-aarch64-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-no-integrated-as'
real-aarch64-linux-android-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Qunused-arguments'
make[3]: *** [/home/saurabh/walleye_test/private/msm-google/scripts/Makefile.build:333: kernel/test.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/saurabh/walleye_test/private/msm-google/Makefile:1100: kernel] Error 2
```

Comment: "... but facing some error related to **clang**." - Eh? The error message is emitted by `g++` (**gcc**), not by *clang*. `gcc` cannot understand `clang` options (like `-Qunused-arguments`).

Comment: Yeah I got that and used again clang++ for compile rest of files.